# xsel not deleting selected text

Tags: xsel

I have been trying to get `xsel --delete` to work to ultimately implement a script to **move** selected material from one editor to another.

According to the [description](https://github.com/kfish/xsel):

```
Delete the contents of the selection
------------------------------------

        xsel --delete

Will cause the program in which text is selected to delete that text. This
really works, you can try it on xedit to remotely delete text in the editor
window.
```

But this does not seem to work (`emacs`, `gedit` and also tried `xedit`).

According to the man page:

```
-d, --delete
       Request that the current selection be  deleted.  This  not  only
       clears  the selection, but also requests to the program in which
       the selection resides that the  selected  contents  be  deleted.
       Overrides all input options.
```

But selected text is not even cleared. Clearing with `--clear` worked in `gedit`, but not in `emacs`.

In all cases I checked if the selected text was "known" with `xsel -p -o` first.

How can I get `xsel --delete` to work? Does this depend on the application listening to `xsel`?

Comment: emacs is not a X application. Don't expect it to follow X to the letter.